# Hyperkahler and symplectic complex geometry: reference?

Tags: complex-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry, complex-manifolds, geometric-representation-theory

I would need some references regarding symplectic and hyperkahler (complex) geometry. My background is mostly from algebraic geometry and I know a little bit the basics on Kahler manifolds.

I would be interested in a book or notes which could introduce me to those subjects with an approach linked to algebraic geometry if possible. Apparently also symplectic and hyperkahler complex geometry are key tools in many areas of representation theory : if someone knew a book which could explain the basics and the reason why these are such important tools, that'd be great!

I've already " Representation theory and complex geometry": I find this is a very good reference but sometimes it is very technical/ I get a little bit lost.

Comment: Some references I like (but are papers/surveys, not books though) are "Huybrechts - Compact Hyperk\"ahler Manifolds: Basic Results (https://arxiv.org/pdf/alg-geom/9705025.pdf)", "Debarre - Hyperk\"ahler manifolds" (https://www.math.ens.fr/~debarre/HKmanifolds.pdf) and "O'Grady - Compact hyperk \"ahler manifolds: an introduction" (https://irma.math.unistra.fr/~pacienza/notes-ogrady.pdf).

Answer (score 4):

I recommend Namikawa's 複素シンプレクティック代数多様体: 特異点とその変形, if you read Japanese.

Comment: Unfortunately not! Thank you anyway :)